Length of swirl on a cone
I have a simple $3$-dimensional arc length problem that surprisingly is not easily available on the Internet. "Assume that we have a cone of height $h$ and diameter $D$, and assume that its axis of symmetry is along the $z$-axis. It is to be striped so that the distance between consecutive points of intersection between a plane through the axis of the cone and the cone is $x$.
I want to calculate the length of the thread.
According to MathWorld, if $a$ is the angular frequency, the length is
$$s(h) = \frac{1}{2} \, h \sqrt{1 + r^2(1 + a^2 h^2) \ } 
+ \frac{1 + r^2}{2ar} \sinh^{-1} \left(\frac{arh}{\sqrt{1 + r^2}}\right).$$
My concern is about "$a$." I do not understand the physical interpretation of "angular frequency" in this scenario. According to the Pythagorean Theorem, the slant height is
$$\sqrt{(D/2)^2 + h^2}.$$
If I want the distance between threads to be $x$, how do I adjust the formula provided by Mathworld to replace $a$ with $x$?

Let's start first from trying to understand the notations on mathworld:
$$x=tr\cos(at)\\y=tr\sin(at)\\z=t$$
In order to avoid notation confusion, I will use capital letters for your quantities: height of the cone is $H$, diameter is $D$ and the distance between threads is $X$.
When $z=H$, we have $x^2+y^2=D^2/4$, or $$H^2r^2=\frac{D^2}4$$
From here you get $$r=\frac{D}{2H}$$
Finally, we look at the thread distance. Without loss of generality, we can consider $at=2n\pi$. After one turn, the angle is $at'=at+2\pi$. With these
$$x=tr\\y=0\\z=t\\x'=t'r\\y'=0\\z'=t'$$
The distance between threads is given by $$X=\sqrt{(x'-x)^2+(z'-z)^2}=(t'-t)\sqrt{r^2+1}=\frac{2\pi}a\sqrt{\frac{D^2}{4H^2}+1}$$
From here you can find $a$. And all you have to do is plug in into the distance equation.

As I do not know the meaning of "angular frequency," I do not know what you mean by $az = n2\pi.$ (I am replacing the parameter "$t$" with the height "$z$.") What is the physical interpretation of the product $az$?

Angular frequency is a term that is related to the period $T$ of an oscillation by the formula $2\pi/T$. If your function is the type $\sin(at)$, you have $a(t+T)=2\pi t/T+2\pi=at+2\pi$, so $\sin(a(t+T))=\sin(at+2\pi)=\sin(at)$. So the interpretation of $az$ is an angle.

This is not a periodic function, though. The height $z$ is changing.

If the thread starts at the tip of the cone along the $xz$-plane, what would be the physical interpretation of $a = 3$?

The first complete turn occurs at $az=2\pi$ or $z=2\pi/3$

Based on your previous comments on "periodic," I am assuming that if a drop of water were to slide along the thread and if were to drop in elevation -- in the direction of the axis of the cone -- by $n2\pi/3$ for some natural number $n$, it would have gone around the cone $n$ times.

Is that correct?

That is correct.

With $H = 40$ and $D = 26$, I got $r = 13/40$ and $a = \frac{\pi}{2} \sqrt{\frac{26^2 + 4\cdot40^2}{40^2}} \approx 3.303$.

Substituting these values into the arc length formula given on Wolfram, I got an arc length of approximately $861.4$

I appreciate your help.

Don't forget to vote/accept the question, if useful

To check the answer, I assumed that threads were tied around the cone at increments of $2$ along its axis and calculated the sum of the circumferences.

I put "sum (2\pi(2n(13/40))), n=1 to 20" into Wolfram and got approximately $857.7$.

That is surprisingly close to the exact answer!
